# how to set one of items to default in ng-options?

Tags: angularjs, default, ng-options, angularjs-ng-options

assume that this is my controller:

```
function MainController(someService) {
    var vm = this;
    // remote call to load items
    var vm.items = someService.loadItems();
    /*
    * item's are something like this:
    * [
    *       {
    *           "id" : 15,
    *           "topic" : "مرکز  شهید بلباسی",
    *           "default" : false
    *       }, {
    *           "id" : 14,
    *           "topic" : "مرکز  شهید کاوه",
    *           "default" : false
    *       }, {
    *           "id" : 13,
    *           "topic" : "مرکز  شهید زین الدین",
    *           "default" : false
    *       }, {
    *           "id" : 4,
    *           "topic" : "مرکز شهید حسین همدانی",
    *           "default" : true
    *       }
    *   ]
    */
}
```

and this is select tag:

```
<select ng-model="vm.searchFilter.itemId"
        ng-options="item.id as item.topic for item in vm.items">
    <option value=""></option>
</select>
```

now, i want to set selected option to item that it's `default` property is true and don't want to use `ng-model` of select tag for this purpose. how can i do that?

Comment: Could you please make a plunker?

Comment: "I don't want to use `ng-model`  **WHY**?  That's how it was intended to function.

Comment: You should mention why you don't want to use ng-model, then only we can help you.

Comment: because data are loaded by remote call, and i don't know the value of `ng-model` before data are loaded.

Comment: dear all, could you answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41493265/how-to-set-default-value-after-ng-options-completed instead of current question?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to pipe the options to a filter.

```
ng-options="item.id as item.topic for item in vm.items | filter:item.default=='true'"
```

Then you should get all options where the option is true.

**Edit:**

to set that option as default value you have to repeat with the option tag and use the `ng-selected` to set the default option. You can try something like that:

```
<option ng-repeat="item in vm.items" value="..." ng-selected="item.default == 'true'">Default options</option>
```

Comment: by this way only items that have `default` value `true` can shown in select, but i want to show all items and only automatically set selected option to item that `default` value of that is `true`, and user can change select value and select other option.

Comment: this is very good trick, and it's work when i remove `ng-model` from select, but i don't want to this. because `ng-model` and `ng-selected` make conflict. also check my update to question

Answer (score 0):

To have an option by default, just make sure that particular option to be set in the `ng-model` of the `select` tag.

```
<select ng-model="defaultVal"
        ng-options="item.id as item.topic for item in vm.items">
    <option value=""></option>
</select>
```

And now select a default value in controller

```
$scope.defaultVal = items[3].id;
```